# UNIX: Is there an opposite for the SIG_IGN?

Tags: c, linux, unix, signals

Hello I am making a program in c and I need to make a `signal(SIGINT, SIG_IGN);` but I need then at a certain point in the code to stop ignoring those signals, is there something like that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can set a signal to use its default signal handling by passing `SIG_DFL` to `signal`.

```
signal(SIGINT, SIG_DFL);
```